# How to find three consecutive letter and number patterns in a string

Tags: python, regex, text-parsing

I am working with strings that include letters, numbers and special characters.

I am trying to create a Python function that detects 3 'consecutive patterns' and returns true or false according to their presence. An example of pattern is the following '1/y2'.

Here four example string is (y1 and b1 and patterns followed by special character '*' will be ingored see below)

1. string1 = '1/y1;1/y2;1/y3;1/y4;1/y6;2/b4;5/b5' -> True (because 1/y2, 1/y3, 1/y4 are consecutive)
2. string2 = '1/y2;1/y3;1/y4*;2/y6;2/b4;8/b5' -> False (no consecutive pattern since third element has special character '*' and need to be excluded)
3. string3 = '1/y2;1/y3;9/y4' -> False (not a consecutive pattern because the last element starts with 9.)
4. string4 = '1/y2;1/y3;1/y4*' -> False (not a consecutive pattern because the last element is followed by '*')
5. string5 = '1/y2;1/y3;9/y4,2/y2;2/y3;2/y4' -> True (consecutive pattern is 2/y2;2/y3;2/y4)
6. string6 = '1/y1;1/y2;1/y3;2/b1;2/b2;2/b3' -> False (while there are 3 consecutive pattern starting with 1 and 3 consecutive patterns starting with 2, pattern that contains 'y1' and 'b1' need to be ignored).
7. string7 = = '1/y1;1/y2;1/y3;2/b1;2/b2;2/b3;2/b4' -> True (3 consecutive pattern is 2/b2;2/b3;2/b4)

Here is my though processing:

1. MATCH pattern that starts with a 'b' or a 'y' followed by a number (i.e. b2, b4, y11, y6)
2. EXCLUDE from the match if the previous pattern has a '*' after it (i.e. b2*)
3. EXCLUDE from the match of previous pattern when 'b' or 'y' is followed by 1 (i.e. b1, y1)
4. BUILD a function that takes the result from regex and finds the consecutive patterns.

Right now I only have a code that works partially. I can find consecutive digits from the regex results with the use of itertools and itemgetter.

```
def three_consecutive_by_pattern(text):
pattern=r'\w(\d+)(?:;|$)'
# extract b or y pattern the ones followed by *
by_list = re.findall(pattern, text)

# convert result from regex to 'numbers'
by_list = [int(x) for x in by_list]

# find sequence of two or more consecutive numbers
consecutive_list = []
for k, g in itertools.groupby(enumerate(by_list), lambda x: x[1]-x[0]):
    final_list = list(map(itemgetter(1), g))    
    consecutive_list.append(final_list)

# from list remove matches for y1 and b1
list_more_than_3_by = [[ion for ion in sub if ion != 1] for sub in consecutive_list]
list_more_than_3_consecutive_by = []

# find sequence of more than 3 numbers. If present return true
for item in list_more_than_3_by:
    if len(item) >= 3:
        list_more_than_3_consecutive_by.append(item)
if list_more_than_3_consecutive_by:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

This performs correctly on string 1 and string 2, but fails on string 3 and string 4.

I was thinking to change the regex into:

```
r'([1-9]\/\w\d+)(?:;|$)'
```

But I need to change when I 'change results from regex to numbers' and I believe create multiple lists, depending on how the pattern starts?

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming the numbers could be of any magnitude (e.g., `'1y1000;1y1001;1y1002'` satisfies the requirement), use of a regular expression will not help because, clever as some are, they can't perform arithmetic.

Comment: Unclear, however if you only need to check the first digit in the first three elements plus verify the pattern, try something [like this demo](https://regex101.com/r/N88gPk/1). @CarySwoveland explained that it's not possible to check for incrementing number by regex alone (you need a callback function for that).

Comment: Regex can't count. Is that what you are asking ?

Comment: No, the regex is only the starting point. The rest of the function is what I need to tweak. It works fine right now only if the pattern the patterns share the same first three characters i e. 1/y2;1/y3;1/y4, these I consider consecutive so the function should return true. But it does not work  if the first or third characters are different such as 1/y2;1/y3;9/y4, these are not consecutives because of the 9 in the third pattern and should return false.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use case for using a lookahead:

```
import re


samples = [
    '1/y1;1/y2;1/y3;1/y4;1/y6;2/b4;5/b5',
    '1/y2;1/y3;1/y4*;2/y6;2/b4;8/b5',
    '1/y2;1/y3;9/y4',
    '1/y2;1/y3;1/y4*'
]

regex = re.compile(r'(\d/[a-z])(\d+)(?=;\1(\d+);\1(\d+);)')


result = {}
for n, sample in enumerate(samples):
    result[sample] = False
    for match in re.findall(regex, sample):
        if int(match[-1]) == int(match[-2]) + 1 == int(match[-3]) + 2:
            print(f'True: {n}, {sample} {match[1:]}')
            result[sample] = True
        else:
            print(f'False: {n}, {sample} {match[1:]}')
    else:
        print(f'False: {n}, {sample} (no match)')

print(result)
```

Result:

```
True: 0, 1/y1;1/y2;1/y3;1/y4;1/y6;2/b4;5/b5 ('1', '2', '3')
True: 0, 1/y1;1/y2;1/y3;1/y4;1/y6;2/b4;5/b5 ('2', '3', '4')
False: 0, 1/y1;1/y2;1/y3;1/y4;1/y6;2/b4;5/b5 ('3', '4', '6')
False: 0, 1/y1;1/y2;1/y3;1/y4;1/y6;2/b4;5/b5 (no match)
False: 1, 1/y2;1/y3;1/y4*;2/y6;2/b4;8/b5 (no match)
False: 2, 1/y2;1/y3;9/y4 (no match)
False: 3, 1/y2;1/y3;1/y4* (no match)
{'1/y1;1/y2;1/y3;1/y4;1/y6;2/b4;5/b5': True, '1/y2;1/y3;1/y4*;2/y6;2/b4;8/b5': False, '1/y2;1/y3;9/y4': False, '1/y2;1/y3;1/y4*': False}
```

The output shows which samples are found to be `True` and the `result` contains each sample and whether at least one match also matched the condition.

The magic is in the regex:

```
(\d/[a-z])(\d+)(?=;\1(\d+);\1(\d+);)
```

This matches anything of the form `<single digit>/<single letter><1 or more digits>`, followed by the same pattern of `<single digit>/<single letter>` and any sequence of `<1 or more digits>` - those four groups (the identifying pattern and the three groups of digits) are in each match, and the matches can overlap since the match only concerns the first group, the rest is in a lookahead `(?=...)`.

The above hopefully helps explain, a cleaner implementation:

```
import re


samples = [
    '1/y1;1/y2;1/y3;1/y4;1/y6;2/b4;5/b5',
    '1/y2;1/y3;1/y4*;2/y6;2/b4;8/b5',
    '1/y2;1/y3;9/y4',
    '1/y2;1/y3;1/y4*'
]

regex = re.compile(r'(\d/[a-z])(\d+)(?=;\1(\d+);\1(\d+);)')


def valid(sample):
    for match in re.findall(regex, sample):
        if int(match[-1]) == int(match[-2]) + 1 == int(match[-3]) + 2:
            return True
    return False


result = {sample: valid(sample) for sample in samples}
print(result)
```

Or if you don't like globals (and who does), you could write `valid` as a single function with the pre-compiled regex enclosed in a partial function:

```
import re
from functools import partial


valid = partial(
    lambda sample, regex: any(int(match[-1]) == int(match[-2]) + 1 == int(match[-3]) + 2
                              for match in re.findall(regex, sample)),
    regex=re.compile(r'(\d/[a-z])(\d+)(?=;\1(\d+);\1(\d+);)')
)
```

This is the version I'd use, unless the `valid()` function would be a method of some object anyway, in which case you can make the regex an attribute or class attribute.

Edit: two shortcomings were indicated in the comments by OP:

- `y1` and `b1` should be accepted to start the series;
- if the last element of the series is at the end of the string, no `;` is required

This is the modified solution:

```
import re


samples = [
    '1/y1;1/y2;1/y3;1/y4;1/y6;2/b4;5/b5',
    '1/y2;1/y3;1/y4*;2/y6;2/b4;8/b5',
    '1/y2;1/y3;9/y4',
    '1/y2;1/y3;1/y4*',
    '1/y2;1/y3;9/y4,2/y2;2/y3;2/y4',
    '1/y1;1/y2;1/y3;2/b1;2/b2;2/b3',
    '1/y1;1/y2;1/y3;2/b1;2/b2;2/b3;2/b4'
]

regex = re.compile(r'(\d/([a-z]))(\d+)(?=;\1(\d+);\1(\d+)(?:;|$))')


def valid(sample):
    for match in re.findall(regex, sample):
        if ((int(match[-1]) == int(match[-2]) + 1 == int(match[-3]) + 2) and
                (int(match[-3]) > 1 or match[1] not in ['y', 'b'])):
            return True
    return False


result = {sample: valid(sample) for sample in samples}
print(result)
```

Result:

```
{'1/y1;1/y2;1/y3;1/y4;1/y6;2/b4;5/b5': True, '1/y2;1/y3;1/y4*;2/y6;2/b4;8/b5': False, '1/y2;1/y3;9/y4': False, '1/y2;1/y3;1/y4*': False, '1/y2;1/y3;9/y4,2/y2;2/y3;2/y4': True, '1/y1;1/y2;1/y3;2/b1;2/b2;2/b3': False, '1/y1;1/y2;1/y3;2/b1;2/b2;2/b3;2/b4': True}
```

Note that this is achieved by capturing the series of letters in its own group and checking that it's not `'y'` or `'b'` when the first number is `1` and by checking for a trailing `;` or end-of-line `$` in the lookahead.

As a general tip: if you get or find an answer like this on StackOverflow, don't just copy the code and assume the person that wrote it somehow knows magic. The code works because of relatively simple logic. It's not always easy to come up with, but given the answer, it's a good use of your time to read every detail of it and try to understand why every little part is there. A true understanding of the solution provided is more valuable than the actual solution, and will allow you to write your own, build on the solution and confidently apply it, knowing it actually solves your problem.

Comment: Note that the explanation version prints `no match` for sample `0` as well, since it never breaks from the loop, so after processing all the matches, it still says 'no match' - that could be fixed but I don't think it helps the explanation that much.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the code is much cleaner! Unfortunately I was not clear, the match does not only concern the first group. I included some exceptional cases such as string5, string6, string7. On those the code does not perform correctly. Should I setup multiple regex and then apply the function to the result of each one? Any thoughts?

Comment: string5 and string7 do not match because they doesn't end in `;` - but I see you'd want it to work at the end of the string as well. The special condition of ignoring `b1` and `y1` is something I completely missed, but could be added. I'll add a solution that covers those, although if you understand the solution, adding it should be fairly trivial.